# How to send a form with 2 values ​from javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, forms, send

I have a form and I want from a javascript function to send the form to php with 2 variables that I have in that javascript function

```
function transfer(old_id){
    var select = document.getElementById('trans');
    var button = document.getElementById('send_id');
    button.addEventListener('click',function(){
        var selectedOption = select.value;
        alert(selectedOption);
        alert(old_id);
        document.delete_user.submit();
    });
}
```

I want this line (document.delete_user.submit ();) to send the variables to php: selectedOption and old_id

Comment: Please use ajax call to send data from your form to php

Comment: @Amit — There's no need for that … and it would stop the new page loading with the response from the submission.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the form to send the data, then you need to have a form control with the `name` you want and the value you want.

If the data exists only in a variable (and isn't already in a form field) then you need to put it in a form field.

Either set the `value` property of an existing one (which you can get with, for example, `getElementById`) or create a new one (you'd generally want to use a hidden input for this) and append it to the form.

Comment: Exactly, these data are ids that are not in the form, do you recommend putting hidden inputs? Thank you anyway.

Comment: @RubenAmezcua — that is what the last paragraph says

Comment: It wasn't the exact way I wanted to send the data, but it works so thanks.